# Prevent ItemCommand from firing on refresh

Tags: asp.net, command, refresh, repeater

I have a web control that contains a repeater with a button that uses a command to add items to a nested repeater

```
control ->
  Rounds - [+] (add group) ->
    Groups
```

As far as I can tell I need to use the `ItemCommand` so I can pass the argument of the round `ID` that I will add the group to, however when I perform an add command and then refresh the page the command is fired again.

I do not want this to happen, is there some way of knowing that the browser is going through a refresh, than maybe I can set a cookie or session variable?

Using redirect doesn't seem to work as I am using a session variable to store the list of rounds and to ensure I only have one instance of this variable at anyone time I remove it and add it as new when the page first opens, and this seems to cause the list to be reset.

Here is the code for the `ItemCommand` event.

```
        protected void RoundsRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "AddGroup")
        {
            if (e.CommandArgument.ToString().AsID() > 0)
            {
                Control ctrl = e.Item.FindControl("RuleGroupListctrl");

                if (ctrl != null && ctrl is RuleGroupList)
                {
                    CompetitionRuleGroup grp = new CompetitionRuleGroup();

                    CompetitionRound currentRound = Rounds.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Round == e.CommandArgument.ToString().AsID());
                    grp.CompetitionID = currentRound.CompetitionID;
                    if (currentRound != null)
                        currentRound.CompetitionRuleGroups.Add(grp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you controlling `IsPostBack` in the `Page_Load`?Wouldn't it solve your problem?

Comment: I have tried using ispostback and iscallback in my page where I set the session variable. However Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); always sets these values to false and so using this causes my variable to be reset. Otherwise in the web control, the IsPostBack is always true, when calling the ItemCommand event and when refreshing the screen, so I can't differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions.

1. have you putted your web control in `autopostback=false` mode ?
2. why not putting all of your `page_load` definitions in

   ```
   if (!page.ispostback())
   ```

   ?

this will skip the `page_load` everytime except from the first `page_load`.

Comment: add more details if you meant for something else.

Comment: I have tried using ispostback and iscallback in my page where I set the session variable. However Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); always sets these values to false and so using this causes my variable to be reset. Otherwise in the web control, the IsPostBack is always true, when calling the ItemCommand event and when refreshing the screen, so I can't differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect to the same page at the end of your `ItemCommand` handler

```
Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx");
```

What is called Post-Redirect-Get(PRG)-Pattern.

http://www.andypemberton.com/engineering/the-post-redirect-get-pattern/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: The problem is that as I have a session variable that is set to a new instance when the page first loads, this means that the liost is empty after a redirect.

Comment: I have tried using ispostback and iscallback in my page where I set the session variable. However Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); always sets these values to false and so using this causes my variable to be reset.

Comment: @Kieran: Ugly but would work: use a Session variable `YourPagePostback`, set it to `true` before the `Response.Redirect`, check it in page_load, remove it from session.